# Replacement for ListBlobs in Azure.Storage to iterate through both containers and blobs

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We were using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob library to iterate through both blobs and containers inside a particular container, like this:

```
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = GetContainerByName(containerName) ;
List<IListBlobItem> blobItems = cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs().ToList();
{
    if (blobItem is CloudBlobDirectory cloudBlobDirectory)
    {
       ...
 
    }
    else if (blobItem is CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob)
    {
 
      ...
    }
```

Now we have decided to switch to Azure.Storage.Blobs and I don't see no easy replacement

```
BlobContainerClient cloudBlobContainer = GetContainerByName(containerName);
List<BlobHierarchyItem> blobItems = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlobsByHierarchy().ToList();
var test = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlobs();
```

both return only blobs, not second level containers and

```
new BlobServiceClient(_connectionString).GetBlobContainers();
```

returns containers, but not under specific container.
What I want is to be able to iterate through layer by layer: find directory -> get all blobs for this directory and all sub-directories on each layer.
Is it possible?

Comment: I am also trying to switch from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob to Azure.Storage.Blobs but have not found much information about replacing the old methods. Do you know of any links that deal with that or give example code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. It will fetch all blob folders and blobs at the root level by fetching 10 items per request.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString =
                "connection-string";
            string containerName = "container-name";
            BlobContainerClient client = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
            var result = client.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(delimiter:"/");
            List<string> blobFolders = new List<string>();
            List<BlobItem> blobs = new List<BlobItem>();
            string continuationToken = null;
            int pageSize = 10;
            do
            {
                await foreach (var blobPages in result.AsPages(continuationToken, pageSize))
                {
                    continuationToken = blobPages.ContinuationToken;
                    blobFolders.AddRange(blobPages.Values.Where(b => b.IsPrefix).Select(b => b.Prefix));
                    blobs.AddRange(blobPages.Values.Where(b => b.IsBlob).Select(b => b.Blob));
                }
            } while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(continuationToken));
        }
    }
}
```